# Would you use xinetd, if you could start from scratch?

Tags: linux

I guess most uses of xinetd are because of historical reasons.

Would you use xinetd, if you could start from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting some other program be the super server, passing sockets as file descriptors, is still a thing.  [systemd can do it](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/inetd.html),  although without legacy features of inetd.

A more useful question to ask is how do you want a given program to accept sockets and possibly fork tasks. Usually, software intended to be a network service does this itself. Sometimes, a thing is easier done reading from stdin and writing to stdout. Or, zero running workers (only the super server) could be desirable when there is no work to do.